# DNS leaks on a vpn server

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, vpn, vps

I have set up an openvpn server on a vps, everything is running as it should.

I have not configured any DNS settings.

My question is. If i do an extended leak test at dnsleaktest.com, i can indeed see that my isp is handling the DNS queries yet if i toggle the 'use google as the fallback' in the openvpn app on my android,  i will see a list of google servers. So is this still a leak?

Would this go away if i set up my own DNS servers that were tied to the ip address of my vpn server?

Cheers

Comment: Yes.  If this VPN is designed for privacy to obscure your internet usage - then ALL traffic should be passing through the VPN, including DNS. As it is, you are doing split tunneling it sounds like, and that won’t give you any privacy.